# Android AutoCompleteTextview click not working

Tags: android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview, simpleadapter

I tried AutoCompleteTextView and getting the values but i can't get the values in the click event of the autocompletetextview this is my layout

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/atv_places"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lin"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/et_chat"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/searchblue"
    android:drawablePadding="4dp"
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="5dp"
    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
    android:hint="Search contacts..."
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

and my click event code to get the values i populate through adapter. I cant get the clicked values or can't work with the toast.

```
  atvPlaces = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.atv_places);

    mTxtPhoneNo = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mmWhoNo);
    mAdapternew = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), mPeopleList,
            R.layout.row, new String[] { "Name", "Phone" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2 });
    atvPlaces.setAdapter(mAdapternew);
    atvPlaces.setThreshold(1);

    atvPlaces.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View arg1, int index,
                long arg3) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "auto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) av.getItemAtPosition(index);

            String name  = map.get("Name");
            String number = map.get("Phone");
            atvPlaces.setText(""+name+"<"+number+">");  

        }



    });
```

Comment: dont use Toasts for debugging, use Log.* methods instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not getting what is problem in your code but below code i made from your code and its working fine, check by yourself.

```
 AutoCompleteTextView atvPlaces = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atv_places);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mPeopleList=new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap h1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        h1.put("Name","name1");
        mPeopleList.add(h1);

        HashMap h2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        h2.put("Name","name2");
        mPeopleList.add(h2);

        final SimpleAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mPeopleList,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, new String[] { "Name"}, new int[] {
                android.R.id.text1});

        atvPlaces.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        atvPlaces.setThreshold(1);

        atvPlaces.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View arg1, int index,
                                    long arg3) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "auto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) av.getItemAtPosition(index);

                String name  = map.get("Name");
                String number = map.get("Phone");

            }



        });
```

Comment: Thank you its working fine now when i use android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item as my layout but not working when i use my custom layout  R.layout.row

Comment: @sinceksaji Add android:id="@android:id/text1" to your custom text view. I know it's really late to receive this answer, but I was working on the same thing these days and the click on the item didn't work because the id of the view was missing from my custom xml layout.